# COUNT with Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count

I have a query where the end user would like a total number of dispensers at a location - even though they're already grouped by location and the total number of dispensers can be seen, they still want that Count column.

Here is the query, which is summing the total number of gallons dispensed by each machine at a location -

```
SELECT nt.COSTCENTER AS "CostCtr",
s.DAD AS "D.A.D.",
s.DIVISION AS "Division", 
nt.DISPENSER AS "Model Name",
nt.SERIALNBR AS "Serial",
nt.CLRNTSYS AS "Sys",
SUM (CASE WHEN nt.CLRNTSYS ='CCE' THEN nt.GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "CCE gals",
SUM (CASE WHEN nt.CLRNTSYS ='BAC' THEN nt.GALLONS ELSE 0 END) AS "BAC gals"
FROM TableNT nt 
JOIN TableSTORE s ON nt.COSTCENTER = s.COSTCENTER
WHERE nt.BOOKDATE >= '01-JAN-18' AND nt.BOOKDATE <= '31-AUG-18'
AND nt.CLRNTSYS IN ('CCE','BAC')
AND nt.TRANCODE = 'DISP'
AND nt.DISPENSER <> 'BYHAND'
GROUP BY nt.COSTCENTER, nt.DISPENSER, nt.TINTERSERIALNBR, nt.CLRNTSYS, s.DAD, s.DIVISION
ORDER BY nt.COSTCENTER, nt.DISPENSER;
```

Most locations only have one dispenser.  Some have two or three or four.  If I do a COUNT (DISTINCT nt.DISPENSER), that's going to just return "1" every time because each record is per dispenser.  Is there a way for me to put the total number of dispensers per location?  i.e. if a location has three dispensers, the record for each dispenser at that location will have "3" in a "Number of dispensers" column?  In that way, if they're looking at just one specific record of one dispenser at a location, they will know the total number of dispensers available at that location (if that makes sense)?

ADDENDUM - Here's an example of what I might want for results, with the number of Dispensers at each Cost Center at the end.  Hope this clarifies.

```
CostCtr|D.A.D. |Division|Model Name|Serial |Sys|CCE Gals|BAC Gals|Num Of Dsps
701003  01-06-02    01   IFC 8112NP ABCDE   CCE 37616.75 0        1
701004  02-08-25    02   IFC 7012NP 12345   BAC 0        1164.75  2 
701004  02-08-25    02   IFC 8112NP DEFGH   CCE 41843    0        2
701005  01-03-38    01   IFC 411XN  67890   CCE 24847.75 0        1
701006  01-06-02    01   IFC 411XN  IJKHL   CCE 50511.5  0        3
701006  01-06-02    01   CB 800CE   23456   BAC 20       0        3
701006  01-06-02    01   CB 2000    MNOPQ   CCE 110      0        3
```

Comment: Seems like you want a *group count*: `count(*) over (partition by whatever_columns_determine_location)`

Comment: And location means what in your query?  Tinter refers to what?  The question is quite unclear.

Comment: Sorry - I edited to clear up a couple of mistakes and add some example records of records and how I would want the Number of Dispensers at each Cost Center in the last column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work - see the count(*) with "over" added. Analytics are pretty cool and designed for just this type of query. This is @doeneth's suggestion in the comments.

```
SELECT nt.COSTCENTER AS "CostCtr"
    ,s.DAD AS "D.A.D."
    ,s.DIVISION AS "Division"
    ,nt.DISPENSER AS "Model Name"
    ,nt.SERIALNBR AS "Serial"
    ,nt.CLRNTSYS AS "Sys"
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN nt.CLRNTSYS = 'CCE'
                THEN nt.GALLONS
            ELSE 0
            END) AS "CCE gals"
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN nt.CLRNTSYS = 'BAC'
                THEN nt.GALLONS
            ELSE 0
            END) AS "BAC gals"
    ,count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY nt.COSTCENTER) AS "Num OF Dsps"
FROM TableNT nt
INNER JOIN TableSTORE s ON nt.COSTCENTER = s.COSTCENTER
WHERE nt.BOOKDATE >= '01-JAN-18'
    AND nt.BOOKDATE <= '31-AUG-18'
    AND nt.CLRNTSYS IN (
        'CCE'
        ,'BAC'
        )
    AND nt.TRANCODE = 'DISP'
    AND nt.DISPENSER <> 'BYHAND'
GROUP BY nt.COSTCENTER
    ,nt.DISPENSER
    ,nt.TINTERSERIALNBR
    ,nt.CLRNTSYS
    ,s.DAD
    ,s.DIVISION
ORDER BY nt.COSTCENTER
    ,nt.DISPENSER;
```

Comment: OVER (PARTITION BY) is a new one on me!  Let me try that out!

Worked exactly as I want - thank you!  Learn something new every day!

Comment: Further reading, if you're interested: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

Answer (score 0):

Where is the location column in your SQL Query above?

A simple query that you can adjust would be ;

```
SELECT LOCATION, COUNT(DISPENSER)
FROM YOUR TABLE
GROUP BY LOCATION
order by 1;   -- 1 means first column
```

For testing purpose creating a simple example below;

```
CREATE TABLE "TEMP_TABLE" ("LOCATION" VARCHAR2(20), "DISPENSER_NAME" VARCHAR2(20))
REM INSERTING into TEMP_TABLE
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into TEMP_TABLE (LOCATION,DISPENSER_NAME) values ('LOCATION1','Loc 1 - Dispenser 1');
Insert into TEMP_TABLE (LOCATION,DISPENSER_NAME) values ('LOCATION2','Loc 2 - Dispenser 1');
Insert into TEMP_TABLE (LOCATION,DISPENSER_NAME) values ('LOCATION3','Loc 3 - Dispenser 1 ');
Insert into TEMP_TABLE (LOCATION,DISPENSER_NAME) values ('LOCATION1','Loc 1 - Dispenser 2');
Insert into TEMP_TABLE (LOCATION,DISPENSER_NAME) values ('LOCATION2','Loc 2 - Dispenser 2');
Insert into TEMP_TABLE (LOCATION,DISPENSER_NAME) values ('LOCATION1','Loc 1 - Dispenser 3');
Insert into TEMP_TABLE (LOCATION,DISPENSER_NAME) values ('LOCATION2','Loc 2 - Dispenser 3');
Insert into TEMP_TABLE (LOCATION,DISPENSER_NAME) values ('LOCATION3','Loc 3 - Dispenser 2');
Insert into TEMP_TABLE (LOCATION,DISPENSER_NAME) values ('LOCATION4','Loc 4 - Dispenser 1');
Insert into TEMP_TABLE (LOCATION,DISPENSER_NAME) values ('LOCATION1','Loc 1 - Dispenser 4');
Insert into TEMP_TABLE (LOCATION,DISPENSER_NAME) values ('LOCATION5','Loc 5 - Dispenser 1');
Insert into TEMP_TABLE (LOCATION,DISPENSER_NAME) values ('LOCATION4','Loc 4 - Dispenser 2');
```

And then you can select the data as per your requirements ;

```
select location, count(dispenser_name)
from temp_table
group by location
order by 1
;
```

which gives you ;

[image]

Comment: Sorry - location is the "Cost Center".

Comment: SUM doesn't work since DISPENSER isn't a number.  I need a COUNT of the total dispensers per Cost Center - so if a Cost Center has three dispensers, it will have three records with the information for each dispenser per record, but I would need the Count to be "3" with each record for that Cost Center.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Well you may use COUNT instead since you need to count the dispensers. I have modified my answer a little for you. 

(Dont forget to mark the answer as correct if it suits u).